# kotlin, how to sort a list and filter out the some object at sametime

Tags: kotlin, sorting, filter

With kotlin it has `sortedByDescending` for sorting a list.

If the list has some null object and some object which has certain value, when do the sorting it would like to filter out those items, how to do it?

```
        class TheObj (val postTime: Long, val tag: String)

        val srcList = mutableListOf(
            TheObj(2022, "a"),
            TheObj(2020, "b"),
            null,
            TheObj(2021, "c"),
            TheObj(2020, "invalid")
        )
        
        /////////////
        // would like to filter out the null object and the object has tag=="invalid" in the sorted list

        val desSortedList = srcList.sortedByDescending { obj -> obj.postTime }//<== this does not work
        desSortedList.forEach{ s -> println(s.postTime) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the nulls first, and then the ones with the "invalid" tag before sorting, like this

```
val desSortedList = srcList.filterNotNull().filter { it.tag != "invalid" }.sortedByDescending { it.postTime }
desSortedList.forEach{ println(it.postTime) }
```

You could combine the two filters like this but then you'll have that the resulting type is still a list with nullable objects meaning you have to add `!!` later on:

```
val desSortedList = srcList.filter { it != null && it.tag != "invalid" }.sortedByDescending { it!!.postTime }
desSortedList.forEach{ println(it!!.postTime) }
```

Comment: thanks @lvo! can the other one (`the object has tag=="invalid"`) be filtered out is the same `sortedByDescending()` call? I guess not.

Comment: @lannyf I totally overlooked the tag requirement. I added some more info